# Variable name is another variable

Tags: python

This sounds like a strange question, so i'll add the code below

```
red = '○'
black = '●'

board = [['','','','','','',''],
         ['','','','','','',''],
         ['','','','','','',''],
         ['','','','','','',''],
         ['','','','','','',''],
         ['','','','','oke','','']]

def printboard():
    print((((str(board).replace('],', '\n')).replace(',', '')).replace('[', ' ')).replace(']', ''))

def place(colour):
    printboard()
    column  = int(input(colour + ', what row do you wish to place your token in? (1-'+str(len(board[0]))+')'))
    for i in reversed(range(len(board))):
        if not board[i][column-1]: 
            board[i][column-1] = colour  <--- I want colour to be the black or white circle depending on 'colour'
            break


place('red')
printboard()
```

Many thanks, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: @bphi oh right, the question in in the code. So if the variable colour is 'red' then it is the variable called red. Thanks

Comment: Your `printboard()` is not beautiful. Try a loop and the `join()` the items.

Comment: Why not simply call `place(red)` or `place(black)` instead of `place('red')` and `place('black')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is technically possible to start messing with variable names in Python, the much better and more general solution is to use a data structure for this. In this case, a dictionary.

```
colours = { "red": '○', "black": '●' }
```

You can then access the values by name easily:

```
>>> colours["red"]
'○'
```

(You can use any variable in the indexer, just as you can with the index to a list, so you can do `colours[colour]`)